# How do I exclude NaN/NaT/None from a python groupby count, but include the row?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

```
>> df

    Foo     Bar     Number  Date
0   abc     None    NaN     NaT
1   abcdefg None    NaN     NaT
2   abcd    this    1111222 3/8/2017
3   abcd    that    1233336 3/3/2017
4   abcd    what    1346554 3/3/2017
5   abcde   that    8889995 3/9/2017
6   abcde   this    1849552 3/8/2017
7   abcd    that    7418652 3/3/2017
8   abcdef  this    4865154 3/7/2017


>>  df.groupby(['Foo']).size().reset_index(name='Total')
```

If I do it this way, the row is counted as having one value, which it does and I understand that.  I'm not sure how to include the row in the Total, but not actually count None/NaN/NaT value?

Returns:

```
    Foo     Total   
0   abc     1
1   abcd    4
2   abcde   2
3   abcdef  1
4   abcdefg 1
```

Expected result:

```
    Foo     Total   
0   abc     0
1   abcd    4
2   abcde   2
3   abcdef  1
4   abcdefg 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could drop nulls first, then reindex with the unique values of the `Foo` column at the end with a fill value.

```
(df.dropna().groupby('Foo')
            .size()
            .reindex(df.Foo.unique(), fill_value=0)
            .reset_index(name='total'))
```

Or alternatively, you could make your `Foo` column [Categorical](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/categorical.html).

```
df.Foo = pd.Categorical(df.Foo)
df.dropna().groupby('Foo').size().reset_index(name='total')
```

**Demo**

```
>>> (df.dropna().groupby('Foo')
                .size()
                .reindex(df.Foo.unique(), fill_value=0)
                .reset_index(name='total'))

       Foo  total
0      abc      0
1  abcdefg      0
2     abcd      4
3    abcde      2
4   abcdef      1

############################################################################

>>> df.Foo = pd.Categorical(df.Foo)

>>> df.dropna().groupby('Foo').size().reset_index(name='total')

       Foo  total
0      abc      0
1     abcd      4
2    abcde      2
3   abcdef      1
4  abcdefg      0
```

Comment: That was it, thank you!!  I haven't yet used Categorical, but will check it out now.